# Debug Java program to find correct person from listed traits

Tags: java, debugging

I am trying to make a program that takes in the **Name, Sex, Age and/or Country** of a `Person` and outputs the correct `Name` from the `Registry`, when queried with any of the mentioned traits. If such a `Person` does not exist, then the output is "Unknown".

For example,

---

Testcase # 1:

Input:

- Name=Rob Sex=Man Age=42 Country=US
- Name=Robin Sex=Man Age=62 Country=US
- Name=Magda Sex=Woman Age=29 Country=PL
- Name=Peter Sex=Man Age=66 Country=RU
- Name=Pete Sex=Man Age=6 Country=US
- Name=Xiaoling Sex=Woman Age=26 Country=CH

Output:

- Required output criteria: **Age=6 Country=US**

Therefore, the program should return a `Person` of `Age=6` and `Country=US`, which is "**Pete**". However, my code is returning "Unknown".

---

Testcase # 2:

Input:

- Name=John Sex=Man Age=46 Country=UK
- Name=Anita Sex=Woman Age=22 Country=NL
- Name=Keiko Sex=Woman Age=37 Country=JP
- Name=Denny Sex=Man Age=13 Country=NL
- Name=Mirjam Sex=Woman Age=28 Country=BE
- Name=Johnny Sex=Man Age=8 Country=UK
- Name=Anna Sex=Woman Age=71 Country=SW
- Name=Fred Sex=Man Age=51 Country=NL
- Name=Frederique Sex=Woman Age=51 Country=FR
- Name=Rob Sex=Man Age=42 Country=US
- Name=Robin Sex=Man Age=46 Country=US
- Name=Magda Sex=Woman Age=29 Country=PL
- Name=Peter Sex=Man Age=66 Country=RU
- Name=Pete Sex=Man Age=66 Country=US
- Name=Frederique Sex=Woman Age=51 Country=FR
- Name=Xiaoling Sex=Woman Age=26 Country=CH

Output:

- Required output criteria: **Name=Xiaoling**

Therefore, the program should return a `Person` of `Name=Xiaoling`, which is "**Xialong**. However, my code is returning "Unknown".

---

My code:

```
class Solution {

    private static class Person {
        private String Name = "Unknown";
        private Map<String, String> Traits = new TreeMap<>();
    }

    // constructs person from given input
    private static Person ConvertRawInputToPerson(String rawInput) {
        Person person = new Person();
        String[] traits = rawInput.split(" ");
        for (String trait : traits) {
            String[] keyValuePair = trait.split("=");
            String key = keyValuePair[0];
            String value = keyValuePair[1];
            if (key.equals("Name")) {
                person.Name = value;
            } else {
                person.Traits.put(key, value);
            }
        }
        return person;
    }

    private static boolean StringEquals(String left, String right) {
        return left.equals(right);
    }

    private static boolean HasTrait(Map<String, String> traits, Map.Entry<String, String> soughtTrait) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> trait : traits.entrySet()) {
            if (StringEquals(trait.getKey(), soughtTrait.getKey())
                    && StringEquals(trait.getValue(), soughtTrait.getValue())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    static class Registry {
        List<Person> mPersons = new ArrayList<>();
        void add(Person person) {
            mPersons.add(person);
        }

        Person findMatchingPersonByRawTraits(String rawTraits) {
            Person soughtPerson = new Person();
            String[] traits = rawTraits.split(" ");
            for (String trait : traits) {
                String[] keyValuePair = trait.split("=");
                String key = keyValuePair[0];
                String value = keyValuePair[0];
                soughtPerson.Traits.put(key, value);
            }

            for (Person person : mPersons) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> soughtTrait : soughtPerson.Traits.entrySet()) {
                    if (HasTrait(person.Traits, soughtTrait)) {
                        return person;
                    }
                }
            }
            return new Person();
        }
    }

    // Entry point
    private static String GetNameFromRegistryByTraits(String[] rawRegistry, String soughtTraits) {
        Registry registry = new Registry();
        for (String rawInput : rawRegistry) {
            registry.add(ConvertRawInputToPerson(rawInput));
        }
        Person person = registry.findMatchingPersonByRawTraits(soughtTraits);
        return person.Name;
    }
```

---

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem here

```
        for (String trait : traits) {
            String[] keyValuePair = trait.split("=");
            String key = keyValuePair[0];
            String value = keyValuePair[1]; <<<<<<< your code has index 0, make it 1
            soughtPerson.Traits.put(key, value);
        }
```

this will get your first case done
for second: you are searching Name in Traits, but while Converting from Raw data you are Not putting that into `Traits`, you are adding to `Name` instance variable

notice this

```
if (key.equals("Name")) {
                person.Name = value;
            } else {
                person.Traits.put(key, value);
            }
```

so while checking data, check if key is `Name`, then search in Name not `Traits`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Can you slightly elaborate on the second case, please?

Comment: Ok. there are 2 parts in your program. 1) parse raw data and put that in Person right, and rest go in Map Traits right. 2) you parse the input to check the Traits of person. while checking you should in Name variable instead of Trait

Comment: for second case you are only checking in Traits, you should also check for Name.